# Is it true that$\log(1+p/100)\approx p/100$?

Tags: logarithms

I found in a book that $\log(1+p/100)\approx p/100$?

Is this true? I've tried to plot the two functions and they look very different and diverging as $p$ gets large. Can you help me understand?

Comment: $\log (1+x)\approx x$ is the linear version of the Taylor expansion.  It is only meant to be useful for small $x$.

Comment: Hence, the approx above is OK for $p$ small?

Comment: Exactly. $\quad$

Comment: $\log(1 + x) \approx x$ for $x$ too close to $0$.

Comment: You certainly saw it on your "plot of the two functions": the line is tangent to the curve at $p=0.$

Comment: It's true when $p$ approaches $0?$ Formally, $\log(1+x)\sim x$ near $x=0.$

Comment: Yes, so $\log(1+p/100)\sim p/100$ near $p=0.$

Comment: Note this is log base $e$, sometimes written $ln$, not base ten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative approach: $\log(x) = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt.$

Therefore,

$$\log\left(1 + \frac{p}{100}\right) = \int_1^{1 + \frac{p}{100}} \frac{1}{t}{dt}. \tag1 $$

In (1) above, the integral may be construed to be equal to the area of the region under the graph of the function $f(t) = \dfrac{1}{t}$ in the range $1 \leq t \leq \left(1 + \frac{p}{100}\right).$

For small $p$, the *height* of the graph will be very close to $~\dfrac{1}{1}~$ throughout this region.  Therefore, for small $p$, the area of the region may be approximated by the area of a rectangle, whose width is $~\left(\frac{p}{100}\right)~$ and whose height is $(1)$.

---

Perhaps a better (but somewhat convoluted) statement is that the ratio of

$$\frac{\log\left(1 + \frac{p}{100}\right)}{\frac{p}{100}}$$

will equal the average value of the function $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{t}~$ in the region $~\displaystyle 1 \leq t \leq 1 + \frac{p}{100}.$

Answer (score 1):

As it has been explained, this just an approximation for, say, $0\leq p\leq 20$.

Consider (and plot) another simple approximation
$$\log \left(1+\frac{p}{100}\right) \simeq \frac {\frac{p}{100} } {1+\frac{p}{200} }$$ This is incredibly better.

Even if is is today a bit too advanced, consider as a "measure" of the error
$$\int_0^{50}\Bigg[\log \left(1+\frac{p}{100}\right)-\frac{p}{100} \Bigg]^2\,dp=0.09731$$ while
$$\int_0^{50}\Bigg[\log \left(1+\frac{p}{100}\right)- \frac {\frac{p}{100} } {1+\frac{p}{200} }\Bigg]^2\,dp=0.00025$$ that is to say almost $400$ times better.